# how to avoid busy waiting between python unrelated processes

Tags: python, subprocess, busy-waiting

i have two python unrelated subprocces, and my wait method was something like the following

```
def wait(self):
    LIMIT = 3
    t0 = time.time()
    while 1:
        message = self.__read_message()

        if message != '\x00':
            break

        if time.time() - t0 > LIMIT:
            time.sleep(0.01)

    return message
```

the read message method is reading a message from a mmap shared memory then delete the message

```
    def __read_message(self):
    with self.__sem2:
        msg = self.mem[self.__PTR_READ:self.__PTR_READ + self.__MSG_LEN]
        self.mem[self.__PTR_READ:self.__PTR_READ + self.__MSG_LEN] = b"\x00" * self.__MSG_LEN
        self.mem.flush()

    return self.__message.unpack(msg)
```

can i improve it so that there is no busy waiting? i have used the subprocess module to create my other python process if this can help

Comment: Can you make `__read_message()` block instead of returning immediately?

Comment: Hard to say without knowing what is happening in `__read_message()`, but this could help:
https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#pipes-and-queues

Comment: @Barmar sorry what do you mean by block? both of the processes are reading form a mmap shared memory, and i used system wide lock, to control their access

Comment: `self.__read_message()` shouldn't return until there's a message to read. Maybe you should use a semaphore to signal from the process that writes to the shared memory.

Comment: you are right, thanks